# Move MongoDB data from Staging server to Production

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have 500,000 documents inside a collection on a staging server, I need to move these documents to the production server.

What is the best way to move this data, can I let mongodb replicate it from staging to production, do I move the data files or do I do an export and re-import?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the mongodump and mongorestore tools. If you only want some of the documents in the collection you can use the --query parameter.

Answer (score 13):

- To dump a collection do

  > mongodump -d dbname -c collectionname

  On a Windows machine this will create a dump folder under the Mongo 'data' folder with bson files
- To restore on a remote host

  > mongorestore -h hostname -d dbname -c collectionname dump\dbname\collectionname.bson

Answer (score 3):

you can also run a db.copyDatabase command from the console or in your app.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/copy-databases-between-instances/

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.

In the destination server > mongo shell > run

```
db.copyDatabase( source_db_name, destination_db_name, source_hostname, username, password)
```

Answer (score -1):

The data files are not per collection so that's out if you want to copy a collection not a full db. If it's per DB you can copy the database files just fine. I am not sure 32 bit vs 64 bit... but i guess you are 64 bit if you run MongoDB.

Now, if the collection exists on both and need to merge then be superb careful to keep _id unique.  mongoimport/mongoexport is your friend.